# Reusing the route in routing module angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a route:

```
{ path: 'route/:id', component: SomeComponent }
```

Now in my header I have made couple different `routerLink`s:

```
<a routerLink="/route/0">route1</a>
<a routerLink="/route/1">route2</a>
<a routerLink="/route/2">route3</a>
```

In `SomeComponent` I have implemented `ngOnInit` like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id === 0) {
      this.title = "title0"
    } else if (id === 1) {
      this.title = "title1"
    }else if (id === 2) {
      this.title = "title2"
    }
  }
```

I am catching `id` from param map and setting the `title` different for every id. In my `.html` I want to display different titles (`{{title}}`) when I click on `routerLink` but when I click on it once the title is set correctly, but when I try to change to another routerLink the title stays the same until I manually refresh the page.

I tried adding `window.location.reload()` to `ngOnInit()` but that of course refreshes the page repeatedly.

How can I achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to grab route parameter using `observable`.

```
   ngOnInit(){
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
            const id = +params.get('id');
            if (id === 0) {
              this.title = "title0"
            } else if (id === 1) {
              this.title = "title1"
            }else if (id === 2) {
              this.title = "title2"
            }
          });
    }
```